# example of continuous integration on binstar

Tags: python, continuous-integration, conda, binstar

recently, [binstar](http://docs.binstar.org/draft/examples.html#SubmitABuildFromGithub) landed continuous integration, being able to build for linux, osx and windows for both 32 and 64 bit. amazing.

is there a specific conda-recipe for a python module wrapping C++ ( heck a C++ library would be also super interesting ) that achieves building for the complete matrix of platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part of building for all the different platforms is the conda recipe, not the Binstar matrix. In that case, you should look at the example recipes in https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes.